# Communication between application processor and base band processor in android

Tags: android-source

I am an android firmware developer.I clone AOSP source code from `android.googlesource.com` . I've found that in android phones there exist two processors : Application processor and base band processor. application processor runs android OS and is responsible for running framework code of android and user applications but base band processor runs software-defined radio protocols that implement protocol stack of GSM. base band processor is responsible for telecommunication operations and is connected to SIM card and RF antenna.

These two processors is connected to each other in some way that depends on phone SoC (System On Chip) and hardware structure.I am now working on Nexus 5x (bullhead) with SoC msm 8992 . I know there is a subsystem in android OS named RIL (Radio Interface Layer) that runs on application processor that handles all requests/responses to base band processor.For example when you want to send a SMS , RIL sends a command with appropriate data to base band processor and then software defined protocol stack processes your request and sends corresponding radio commands to antenna.These messages are named AT commands.

My questions are

1. How application processor and base band processor are connected to each other in Nexus 5x phone ? (serial link or shared memory or ...)
2. How can I send AT command to base band processor in android shell ?(via adb shell)
3. Which node(s) in /dev in android file system is used for communication to base band processor ?
4. There exists an open source version of base band that I can use for bullhead ?

Comment: Please specify Your question: what serial connection You want to use?

Comment: I have nexus 5x and I want to send AT commands to /dev/tty7 . It is connected to modem.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12906522/6950238) answer and small description [here](https://magora-systems.com/serial-port-rs232-and-android/).

Comment: If you are thinking of the `echo` command line program, that is likely not reliable; you should instead use the [atinout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23455758/23118) program for command line invocation of AT command.